# "Too Localized" a reason to close, but not in the FAQ

Tags: discussion, status-completed, too-localized

Since "too localized" is a valid reason to close a question, this should be mentioned in the FAQ.

https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Maybe it's not asked *frequently* enough... ;-D

Answer (score 2):

Good idea! This is now listed under

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close