# Request to re-open a question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

### The question

[Can HTTP headers be too big for browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326210/can-http-headers-be-too-big-for-browsers-closed)

### Why it should be re-opened

This question got closed by 1 moderator as being a duplicate. Even though I clearly stated that the questions marked as possible duplicate didn't answer my question and weren't about the same thing, the question hasn't been reopened yet. It took 9 minutes for my question to get closed and 1 hour after I have flagged it for moderator attention and edited it to highlight that it wasn't a duplicate, I still haven't got moderator feedback about the question.

In the question, it was stated I was looking for the limitation of **browsers** about the size of HTTP Headers. The question title says it's about **browsers**, the question body says it's about **browsers** and I even tagged it with **`[browsers]`**. And yet, it got closed as duplicate of question about the **servers** limitation for HTTP Headers.

There even was someone who added this as comment after it was close :

> Indeed, this is about User-Agent
> limitations, not server ones. If my
> experience is anything to go by,
> chances are those can be a lot lower.
> Voted to reopen. – Wrikken

Comment: Another example why [mods should be able to cast normal close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-vote).

Comment: @ken But even if they can, does that mean they will use the feature?

Comment: @wai: At least they have an option.

Comment: @KennyTM: no, it's not. Look at the comments: a user with insufficient reputation to cast close votes posted a link to the (non-) duplicate a minute before it was closed. The mod presumably acted based on this user's recommendation - which is great, but he probably should have waited a couple of minutes for the author to respond before doing so, *or* returned once the author had clarified to correct the mistake. Casting a single close vote in this case would have required the mod to recognize that it wasn't a clear duplicate... in which case, he probably shouldn't have voted *at all*!

Comment: What sucks now is that the question will get barely no attention at all. Is there anyway to get the question bumped in some short of way ?

Comment: @HoLyVieR If the question is edited, the question will be bumped back to the home page.

Comment: The question has been re-opened now. =)