# Questions migration: enlarge your "belongs on.." suggestion list

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, migration

Will you add http://unix.stackexchange.com to the list of available migration sites which are suggested whenever someone decides to close the question as off-topic?

I also wonder if an option to manually specify an SE site would be of any use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff has stated that there will not be more than 5 migration targets:

[Add a migration path to Pro Web Masters from Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1595/add-a-migration-path-to-pro-web-masters-from-super-user/1704#1704)

If you really think a question would be better off on a site not on the list flag it for moderator attention giving the site. Moderators can migrate to any other site in the network so if they agree it can be moved.

Comment: I understand the list is limited, but smaller sites will never get a chance unless a moderator sees the question (which also overrules the "5 votes needed to migrate" requirement). For that reason, I suggest [destinations should be added to the shortlist based on the question tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags).

Comment: @Jan - by flagging the question you are ensuring that at least one moderator will see the question.

Comment: Indeed, but moderators sometimes wait for others to cast a vote because [they don't want to have a binding vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-vote), even more [in newer sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66245/the-binding-moderator-vote-problem-on-beta-se-sites) (where the boundaries may not even be clear when the site graduates, and regular migrations become possible).

Comment: @Jan - if the question needs to be migrated to a site *not on the current list* then the fact that the moderator's vote is binding is a moot point. Waiting for more flags (or close votes) could lead the question being migrated to the wrong site.

Comment: With my proposal the missing site would become available in the current list, so the possibility of an incorrect migration doesn't change a lot.