# Overly-vague question only seemed overly vague

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

User @mathieurip posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092110/cant-parse-response-into-json-error-when-pushing-rails-app-to-appfog), since closed as not a real question. Mathieurip included 100% of the details available to him:

- AppFog was giving him an odd error on deployment
- The text of the error
- Literally that's it

It looks very vague but it was all that was available, and all that was needed for me to know that it was the same problem I was having, for me to research a solution and post the answer. I understand why the question was closed - it appears much too vague. But it was tagged "appfog", and if you're familiar with AppFog then the question had enough detail. I would like to request that @mathieurip's question be reopened.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092110/cant-parse-response-into-json-error-when-pushing-rails-app-to-appfog

Comment: This was a moderator close, so only another moderator can open it. The question has not been deleted, so it can still go back to a "living" status. A moderator will see this post and with a bit of luck re-open the question (though, having your answer, it doesn't really need it).

Comment: @oded: But i can vote to reopen, right?

Comment: @juergend - Try it. As far as I know, no, not on a moderator close.

Comment: Cheers, thanks @Oded. Is this the right place to get moderator support? I posted this question based on instructions here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57104/how-to-appeal-a-closed-question

Comment: @Oded Just because a mod closed it doesn't mean a mod needs to reopen it.

Comment: @Oded i tried to reopen and successfully done  ..without any message or warning

Comment: @Servy - I recall there were some moderator actions that were binding and could not be reversed. Guess close votes are outside of that.

Comment: @Oded Most aren't, to my knowledge.  Some are, but most aren't.

Comment: @Oded - it's moderator deletes that can't be undone by regular users.

Comment: @NullPointer Thanks much but the question appears to still be closed?

Comment: @ChrisF - Yes, and lots of stuff on [beta sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66245/the-binding-moderator-vote-problem-on-beta-se-sites).

Comment: @Dave - 5 community members need to vote to reopen, whilst only one moderator is needed for closing.

Comment: @Oded thanks. I'm too new to have a reopen button I guess!

Comment: Okay, I'm sold. Reopened.

Answer (score 1):

To this question it appears that the error is very general, and could be a result of all sorts of things.  Your answer is what specific problem *you* had that caused that error, but it's likely completely unrelated to the problem the OP is having that caused that error.  That's why the question needs to be closed.  It doesn't really matter much if the OP can't come up with any more information.  If there isn't enough information to solve the problem (even if it's because it doesn't exist) it's still not appropriate for the site.

Comment: I would tend to agree. At the very least a description of what steps were taken if not an extremely minimal example so that others can test the same scenario exactly would make it a better question.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Without being familiar in that technical subject I couldn't comment.  The OP here is asserting that no more information could possibly be provided, so this answer is written assuming he's correct.  If he's wrong, and there's more information the OP could provide to make the question answerable then obviously if he provides it then that may qualify it for reopening.

Comment: My point is that I'm all about very specific questions, and if it had been me asking, and I hadn't had a lucky break with my breaking change being only one commit back, I wouldn't have had any more details to post than what @mathieurip did.

Comment: @Dave Any the entire point of my answer is that while that's an unfortunate situation to be in, it doesn't mean that the question is appropriate on SO.  Even if you did your homework, put in a lot of effort researching and trying to solve the problem, it really is a hard problem, and there is no more information to find, it doesn't change the fact that the other answerers on SO don't have enough info to solve the problem, so the question needs to be closed.

Comment: @Servy That's fair. I'm sort of contending that he did provide enough information - but that's only because I happened to be naturally reproducing it. You say my solution is probably unrelated; I disagree, I'd put ten bucks on my problem being the same as his at a high level, and on it being useful to him in figuring out the low level issues! BUT it's not as though I can prove that, I'm just going off of the timing & text of the error, and I grant that that's not enough to make the question clearly SO-worthy. Thanks for the attention here, and I appreciate the philosophical clarity too.