# Allow mod to VOTE to close

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a way for moderators to cast a normal, non binding vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-vote)

At present if a mod thinks questions should be closed, they close it.  However a mod cannot **vote** to close.

This means on new sites with very few 1000+ users, that there is no effective voting to close.  So the mod just has to take full control and the users don’t get any say in it.

Therefore allow a mod to cast a **normal vote** as well as a “instant close”.