# How do I view everything in the "close votes" review queue without dismissing them?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

As a moderator, I would like to be able to keep an eye on the questions that are garnering close votes.  I usually don't want to *act* on those; as a mod I have the "big stick" so I don't vote to close unless it's pretty clear.  But as I understand it (please correct me if I'm wrong), if I choose "skip" the question will disappear from my review queue, which is not what I want either.  If it had one vote when I first saw it, and since then it's garnered two or three more, I'd like to be made aware of that.

Is there a no-op path through this queue?

Comment: Jeff's take on the big stick: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74070/149052

Comment: Understood.  I'm talking about cases where it's not yet clear what action should be taken.  Ours is a smaller, younger site where sometimes community consensus isn't completely clear, so in those cases I prefer to allow time for others to weigh in (especially those with enough rep that they can cast these votes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip *is* the no-op. There is now a way for moderator (and high-rep users) to skip through the queue [and then return back to previously-skipped tasks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158239/let-moderators-navigate-the-review-queues-at-will/184309#184309).

***That being said...*** Part of your job as a moderator is to figure out what the community expects to be done in different scenarios, and make it happen - if you're using this as a crutch to avoid making hard decisions, *you're doing it wrong*.

(Same thing goes for non-mods - realistically, anyone using this to go back more than a few dozen reviews is getting a bit crazy with it; if this ends up being abused, we'll probably restrict it.)

Comment: And what if he wants not to avoid hard decision, but just to postpone it until he will have access to reference materials? In Math and Physics it would be kinda natural, wouldn't it? Should the temporary lack of references for making one decision block all the rest of them?

Comment: Sometimes the fact that something has received close votes comes as a surprise and then we have a conversation about the underlying issue as a community.  I can't speak for all mods, but on our site we're not using it to avoid making decisions.  I've wielded the mod-hammer plenty of times too. :-)

Answer (score 5):

There's a barely usable way of doing this; if you click the "review" tab it'll randomly give you another item to review.  The link is shown here:

[image]

It might be the same one, it might be a different one. Allegedly the random post you see is weighted by how many close votes a post already have, but I was able to get both a 4 vote post and a 2 vote post in the same rotation, so it is possible to see other posts even if one has many close votes. You're correct that if you skip something, it's out of your queue (but no one else's) for good.

Note that you can't do the same thing by refreshing the page; the post to review is part of the URL, so F5 always gives you the same item.

Comment: Oh, clever!  I hadn't considered "spin the wheel again and see what happens".  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, review queues aren't really mod friendly.

You can, however, review pending close & re-open votes in the [10K tools](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last30days) lists.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Click on "Most Votes" to see more items, and you can even filter by close reason. All the questions with pending close votes are in there, including questions that may have been pushed out of the review queues.

Comment: Clicking those didn't reveal any more questions, so I suspect this means that there are close votes pending that are more than 30 days old.  (There's no "all" tab for this tools page.)  Drat.  Thanks.