# Reset flag declined warnings due to Close vote burn down

Tags: discussion, review, flags, declined-flags

With the recent [massive burndown of the close vote queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223497/226653) I've found myself banned from flagging despite having a very high flag acceptance rate. Given that the burndown is **NOT** a normal thing. Shouldn't we [temporarily disable the hellban queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/226653) until the burndown is finished? I'm willing to wait out the ban but it doesn't seem logical for a large number of users who are trying to contribute to the moderation of the site to be punished all at once. That seems counter to SOs user moderated credo.

Comment: I don't see how your ban is related to the burn-down of the CVQ. Can you clarify that relationship?

Comment: Flagging hellban occurs when you have a greater than *X* number of declined flags in a week, given that flags are being declined from over a year ago this doesn't seem logical.

Comment: Perhaps the banning should be based on (or heavier weighed towards) flags that were cast recently. Of course I don't know if this is the true cause of your flag ban.

Comment: @Bart nor do I it seems the only logical thing however due to the fact that I've only had 9 declined flags and 222 deemed helpful.

Comment: Ok, I understand now what is happening and that seems unfortunate.

Comment: @rene it was actually predicted by the highest upvoted comment on the linked post.

Comment: That is correct but a dev and a CM counter that in the comments later...I'll leave it to a mod to clarify.

Comment: @rene perhaps I should re-tag this question with [tag:bug] then

Comment: it would be nice if flags from dropped CVQ tasks were "cancelled", not "declined"

Comment: @Mgetz I don't think it is a bug. The site works as specified. It now demonstrates an expected but maybe under anticipated effect. I'm sure someone who is able to look into this will answer/comment.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't think I agree with that.

Comment: To me, this sounds like a problem with the way these are being counted. The flag bans should be applied based on when the flags are cast, but it sounds like they're being factored in based on when they're processed instead. Changing it to the former would eliminate this issue, while still leaving the much-needed flag ban for our worst flaggers (the people who are on their 16th "plz answer thz now" flag, for example).

Comment: @BradLarson "16th "plz answer thz now" flag" - wow.........

Comment: @BradLarson that seems likely, my last declined flag was from the 18th of February... that's well over a week ago.

Comment: @BradLarson The problem with that is if they consistently cast flags which sit in the queue for too long, they will never encounter the flag ban, will never be informed to look at their history, and will continue flagging poorly in the future. Shog told me that using the handle time is simply a more efficient option.

Comment: @animuson and that is why I'm expecting the answer to be "Just wait it out"

Comment: @JanDvorak `"it would be nice if flags from dropped CVQ tasks were "cancelled", not "declined""`  They're already marked "disputed", not "declined"  (Unless it's a mod who handles the flag, despite 3k users being able to handle it).  And because of that, they shouldn't be contributing to the ban.

Comment: Actually, @Servy... See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177752/replace-close-flags-with-close-suggestions/190613#190613

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At this point, it doesn't matter: after 18 hours, you're no longer flag-banned. But [my advice in any case would've been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223382/why-am-i-seeing-the-message-some-of-your-recent-flags-have-been-decline-when-f/223444#223444):

> you might want to spend a bit of time figuring out why - maybe your flags were perfectly appropriate when you raised them but the situation changed by the time they were handled... Or maybe you're flagging things that aren't really problematic.

Remember, the instigation for [the recent change to flag-bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban) was to make them *temporary:* you should never be blocked for more than a week at a time, and generally it'll be less than that. Treat it as an opportunity to learn.

As for the close queue burndown: that's actually *why* you were briefly banned! 10 of the posts you flagged for closure were reviewed in the past week, and 3 of those flags were declined. Note that each of these required the attention of at least 3 reviewers, attention that could've been better directed elsewhere - so again, try to learn from these so that you can improve the accuracy of your flagging going forward. Ultimately, this improved accuracy helps a lot more than having more pile-on flags.

Comment: I do try to keep my declined flags to a minimum, but it is inevitable that some will be declined.