# Make it possible to 'subscribe' to a post

Tags: feature-request, posts, subscription

Often, I will downvote a post because of major spelling / grammar errors. The expectation is that if the post is improved, I would remove my downvote. That's better for everyone.

But how can I be expected to keep track of each of these on my own? Couldn't we do something like this:

> [image]
>
> [image]

It's not perfect, and would probably be an implementation nightmare, but even if only the edit notification part was implemented it would make life easier. And more downvotes would get undone.

I do realize that this would be a problem for edit wars. Couldn't we make the edit notifications stop for those involved after `x` rollbacks? We could even make it a 5k/10k privilege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already in place. Favorites allow you to be notified of any changes to a post.

[How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/192187)

> A question is marked as a favorite by clicking the star beneath the vote counter.
>
> [image: Favorite]

...

> Marking a question as a favorite provides 2 general benefits to you.
>
> 1. It will be listed in your user profile under the tab "favorites". This lets you find it easily when the question may get lost.
> 2. Changes to the question will eventually (but *do not currently*) notify users who have favorited the question. Notifications will include comments to the question, edits, new answers, and edits to answers. This is a way to get updates on questions that you yourself didn't ask.

Comment: Soo... How long has this been status-planned?

Comment: Stuff gets lost pretty easily in the “favorites” tab.

Comment: @Undo It is already in place. For example, I just checked my favorites tab and saw I have ten questions with new activity. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158239/192187 had become [status-completed], so I un-favorited it as I no longer need notifications about it.

Comment: @minitechη That seems a different feature-request altogether

Comment: @AmericanLuke: Yeah, the “eventually” part.

Comment: There are notifications, just not in the supercollider, if I understand you right. You can also check from the little arrow beside your username in the top bar.