# What are the consequences of skipping a close vote review task?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

Does it mean that the question will be removed from my queue? Forever? :-)

Can I vote to close it later?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I've seen the same review after I've skipped it. I think it's re-added if there's another close-vote for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means it won't be shown to you randomly when selecting the next item.

If you navigate to that particular review again (i.e. through the back button on your browser) then you can still act on the review (assuming it hasn't been completed).

Comment: Note, moderators can [navigate review queues at will](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158239/192187).

Comment: @AmericanLuke Ooh, and 10k+ users as well.  Haven't seen that before.  Nice.