# Can our Review History also list the items we have skipped?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, review-history

I often come across review items where I am unsure of an appropriate action to take and skip those items. However, merely skipping the item doesn't educate me as to what I should actually do if I encounter a similar situation again in future and what is the community's general response in those situations.

The history for review items are only recorded when we take any action on them. If we skip the review item, there is no trace of that review item in our history as well.

Can our Review history also list the items we have skipped? This would help us come back to that review item later on and learn about the general response of the community in those cases.

Something like this which is [already implemented for 10K users and moderators only in Close review history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184309/205516) is what I am looking forward to for general users as well (at least for Close, Low Quality and Suggested Edit queues):

> [image: something like this which is implemented for mods]

Comment: I'd love to know my skip count for suggested edits, just so I know my true reject rate.

Comment: I have found that every suggested edit is handled within 5 minutes during each time of the day, wouldn't this be solved by keeping the edit open in a separate tab?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: That is true for SO.. On most of the other sites it easily takes about 2-3 hours for suggested edit to be reviewed completely..

Comment: Is "the general response of the community" a good yardstick to use anyway? Of course this is purely subjective, but there seem to be plenty of people just rubber-stamping things in the Suggested Edit queue :P

Comment: I second this. Was about to write the same suggestion. I understand that it does not becomes a definitive guide, but should give hints.

Comment: I'm working on this now.

Comment: YAY... Thanks @DaveHaney

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Enabled regular user skipped functionality, see text below:

Thanks for suggesting this feature! I have modified the review system to obey the following rules:

- There's now a *show skipped reviews* checkbox and link to *my review history*. The checkbox enables toggling skipped reviews on a history page. The link takes you to your own review history. These options are now available for **all review queues** rather than just the closed queue.
- **MODERATORS** will see the checkbox and the link on all history pages. Mods can see anyone's history and general history. Mods looking at their own history will see skipped reviews by default but can toggle them off with the checkbox. Additionally, when reviewing and reaching the end of the queue, mods will be presented with a link to their own history (which again will show skipped reviews by default).
- **10K USERS** will see the link but only see the checkbox on their own history. 10K users can see their own history and general history. 10K users looking at their own history will see skipped reviews by default but can toggle them off with the checkbox.
- **REGULAR USERS** will see the checkbox but not the link. They will only ever see their own history which will *not* show skipped reviews by default. They will be able to use the checkbox to show skipped reviews.

This will be live in the next production build (> rev 2014.7.2.2352). Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Is there a reason why the checkbox is unavailable for 10k users?

Comment: Yes, after discussing the feature with the community managers, it was decided that 10k users would not be able to view skipped anywhere but on their own review history.

Comment: This feature-request was **for Regular users** - users who are just beginning with Reviews, so that they can learn what should be their response in certain situations. With your implementation, they have gained absolutely nothing. I don't think this implementation adds any sort of value to the current system. The utility of seeing one's skipped items is much higher for newer users than that for established users. Hence, I don't think this feature is [tag:status-completed] and the tag should be removed (it should be status-declined, status-review or whatever but not status-completed).

Comment: @Aditya I'll run it by the community managers and see if I can get an answer to you.

Comment: I'm still waiting to see what has been done, but now I understand I misread and I agree with @Aditya. If it's 10k/moderator only feature it should really be announced as a new question, leaving this one declined or statusless for the time being.

Comment: After discussing this with the community mods, I'm adjusting the functionality to include regular users being able to see skipped reviews.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the new functionality.

Comment: Perfect. Well done. Just checked it on [ubuntu.se] and everything seems just about right. But you said it will be available in build `> rev 2014.7.2.2352`, but I can see it in action in build `rev 2014.7.2.1690` on AU.