# Previous/Next button on review history

Tags: feature-request, review

Looking at the review history it would be nice to have a *Previous* and *Next* button. Something like:

> <kbd>**Review completed** 3 hours ago:                                                                                                 *Add this?* ══> <kbd>Previous</kbd><kbd>Next</kbd>
>
>   user123 reviewed this 3 hours ago: **No Action Needed**</kbd>
>
> #### Answer
>
> ---
>
> 19       Looking at the conceptual beings we can conclude the correct approach would be to
> <sub>votes</sub>     eliminate x and promote y.

The functionality of the buttons would be to bring one to the previous / next review item in ones own history.

Primary reason to make it easier to navigate and look over ones own history.

As a bonus it would be nice to optionally include skipped reviews, [like suggested in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221134/251765). Combined the features would make for a nice way to self-educate, as well as quality check etc. own reviews.

This would typically be on e.g. profile page:

> <kbd>activity</kbd> 
>                ⇓
>      <kbd>reviews</kbd><kbd>suggestions</kbd>

And / or on the *history* page of the review queues – *recent reviews »*.

---

Edit: OK. Perhaps I should not have written this when my review limit was reached for the day. It clashes with the existing functionality when one look up old reviews as one get the *next* button for *new* reviews. But could perhaps be possible in some way.

On the *suggestions* history it might be less complex though.