# Review Items counter is stuck

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, top-bar

On Linguistics.SE, I observe Pending Review items counter stuck. This happens only at this site¹ and it never recovers for several months so far, while I occasionally check these items and submit my reviews.

[image]

The following links are full screenshots taken at Review page and 6 individual history pages.
[(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXVl0.jpg),
[(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDc7k.jpg),
[(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9yh4.jpg),
[(4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQgtI.jpg),
[(5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NFZw.jpg),
[(6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Ksr.jpg),
[(7)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haWl1.jpg)

(¹) Since 2014, it started happening on Politics.SE and several other sites; I failed to find any pattern.

Comment: Oded seems to have forgotten to remove [status-bydesign] ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the number of pending review items, although you may have already reviewed, skipped, or be otherwise-ineligible to review some of them.

For details, see: [Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-much/230802#230802)

Note that you can browse your past reviews, [including those tasks you skipped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221134/can-our-review-history-also-list-the-items-we-have-skipped/234909#234909). If you're curious about the tasks that've been stuck in review the longest, you can [peruse them via SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/linguistics/query/195691/oldest-500-pending-review-tasks).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my rep (2k) apparently does not let me see any of "skipped reviews" checkboxes whatsoever. I don't actually worry since it was pretty easy to cut it away with any html-element-hiding browser plugin and never see this indicator again. Just raised this question because I think it is misleading to show any indicator like "you have N items" and then end up with a blank list.

Comment: Ok, that's actually a bug then, @bytebuster - you should see a link that [looks like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLqlu.png) at the bottom of the /history page for any review queue on Linguistics (since Linguistics is a beta site, 2K should give you access to what are lovingly referred to as "the 10K tools"). Might I trouble you to post a bug report with screenshots of what you *do* see there?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Yes, I have access to Review History link. I have added full screenshots in the body of the question. I used only 1st pages for each review queue, so please let me know if you need all of them. Also, "post a bug report" — did you mean, some external bug-tracking system?

Comment: @bytebuster: this is the bug report system :) I'm thinking those screenshots were all that was requested. BTW, I made another place to go for details and another feature request regarding this notification: [Modulate the review notification's color to reflect changes, or make it dismissible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230833/246931)