# Queue counts inconsistent?

Tags: bug, review, top-bar

Recently, on AskUbuntu, we (chat) were clearing out queues as normal, but then we noticed something strange.

Typically, the 10k+ flag/queue counter is pretty up-to-date in the topbar, which includes ineligible reviews (reviews already completed, etc). And, our review queue counter says 0:

[image]

However, the review queue itself was not empty:

[image]

Why did the (real) count of 6 suddenly vanish from our topbars? Is this a bug?

Answer (score -1):

That counter, among being cache ladened to the point of being almost meaningless, shows the available reviews left for **you** to do, not the total count of reviews left.

So while there are, say 6, review left to do; if you have already reviewed them, or maxed out your daily limits, then you have 0 you can do.

See these questions for more information on this topic.
[What does the number next to the review link in the top bar actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251659/278094)
[Review Items counter is stuck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236412/278094)

Comment: But, [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251698/259230) conflicts the point discussed that it's only mine. And, I've seen that number be non-zero when my personal queue is zero.