# Show number of posts to be reviewed in the review indicator instead of the circular dots

Tags: feature-request, review

[image]

I believe the area of grey circular dots could be better occupied by the *numerical* count of the number posts up for reviewing in that subsection. When there are no posts for reviewing in that subsection, it could be left blank.

One use case for this is that I don't always want to open the `/reviews` page if there's only one item requiring review. I would instead want to focus on a different problem or skip reviewing at that time altogether.

I hope this is easily doable.

Comment: We had that ... the number was always wrong. Let's not go back to that as that faulty number never got fixed in the 6 to 8 years it was broken.

Comment: @rene Well, I wasn't aware of the history. But, I hope a new, better, non-buggy number can be re-introduced nonetheless :)

Comment: related:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304445/experiment-review-needed-indicator-logic-for-sites-that-sometimes-have-empty-qu?noredirect=1&lq=1 and for history sake: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251659/what-does-the-number-next-to-the-review-link-in-the-top-bar-actually-mean and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236412/review-items-counter-is-stuck?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @rene at least the numbers meant something useful, even if not 100% accurate. I really dislike those dots, they mean nothing to me, also buggy (e.g. red dot for a single item), and all in all, I miss the previous UX.

Comment: Grey means stuff is there, red means there is unusually high amounts of stuff there, which for a smaller site is "anything at all" so smaller sites never get just grey dot alone. It's not a bug, it's SBD.

Comment: @Nij Well, the red dot is buggy anyway :( I've tried it a few times, sometimes it works, and several other times it doesn't.