# Skipping the same review multiple times

Tags: discussion, review

I noticed in the review queue that I can skip a single question as many times as I like:

[image: skip image]

It's kind of fun!  And it seems harmless enough from my point of view.  I wonder, though, if it'll throw off the "skip" count in the review stats (or something else I'm unaware of).

Does this matter at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skip is not counted as a review action, it has no meaning towards any badge, and its only purpose is to not have this review item given to you again. This does not block you from reviewing the item if going there directly, or skipping it again.

Until [recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234909/152859), we couldn't see the items we skipped at all, it's just a "nice to have" thing, that's all.

Happy Skipping!