# The close vote queue size is disputed

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

In the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1864027#1864027) it turned out that the [size of the Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) is different for different users.

My number seems always to be correct (because it is the lowest) but other report a difference of almost 400 questions.

I cleared my filters and verified this in IE11, Chrome and FF on Win7/x64 with the same results.

If this is not caching what can be the logical explanation for this difference?

Comment: Maybe my numbers were correct, because they were always higher. ;)

Comment: actually, you are the only one who says it's not OVER 9000.

Comment: But that would mean I could end up with a negative queue size? What would that mean?

Comment: @rene integer overflow? At least we'd find out what datatype is being used.

Comment: This is why my graph shows different numbers! :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The count doesn't include items that are currently pending in the queue that you personally cannot review.  This includes items that you have already acted on, in addition to items that you have skipped and items that are currently being reviewed by other users.  Apparently you've acted on/skipped ~400 more posts than the other users you've compared yourself with.

Comment: And how can I get that number of posts where I acted on or are skipped? How is the real size of the queue determined?

Comment: Since you have > 10K on Stack Overflow, you can follow the instructions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158239/let-moderators-navigate-the-review-queues-at-will/184309#184309) to view items you've skipped, @rene. Alternately, just [open the review dashboard](http://stackoverflow.com/review) in a browser where you're not logged in.

Comment: @Shog9 That does it! Thanks