# If a user edits a closed question and checks the "Submit for review" option, does that mean only 2 reopen votes are needed to reopen the question?

Tags: support, edits, vote-to-reopen

Assume an SE site is configured so that 3 reopen votes suffice to reopen a question, and that one needs at least 3k rep to cast a reopen vote.

If a user with less than 3k rep makes an edit and checks the option "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening.", does that mean that one only needs 2 other reopen votes to reopen the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening" checkbox has no effect other than creating a reopen queue entry. This is the case even if the editor has more than 3K rep - unless they explicitly click on the vote to reopen button then they haven't voted.

Comment: Moreover, a moderator can [check the box and it won't instantly reopen the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377497/323179).